# MySQL & PHP: Using an INPUT BUTTON to redirect to new page of data

Tags: php, mysql, database, redirect, onclick

I have some code within my php script that connects to my database, and then displays a list of food items. It works pretty well, but now I need to create a button that links to another page for each specific item in the table. I know this is wrong, but I'm trying to learn so that's why I'm here.

```
require("database.php");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM entrees_menu_table");

echo "<table width='1024' border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='5' align='center'>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Menu Items</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Add to Order</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'><img src='./img/burger.png'></td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['entrees_item'] . "</td> <td align='center'> <input type='button' value='More Info' onclick='location.href('http://www.gmail.com');'> </td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['entrees_price'] . "</td> <td align='center'> <input type='button' value='Add to Order' onclick=''> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
```

In the above code, the MORE INFO input button needs to redirect to a new page, and display the entree_item_description from my database for each entrees_item. Would I have to completely re-do my entire code to make this happen? I'm lost so far, and was trying to test out onclick with a location, but it's not working at all.

Comment: `<a href="more_info.php?id=$id">MORE</a>`

Comment: That works as an href, but it needs to be a button. Also, still a confused how the new redirected page will grab the entree_item_description from the database that matches the item the user selects to have more info about.

Comment: it's the concept that matters. buttons can act just like links. as for the next page, you pass along the id of the item button that got clicked as a query parameter, exactly as I did in my sample link.

Comment: Oh I see. The ID from the database of the Item gets passed over into the new page. Ok, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @ValleyDigital I agree with Marc B the concept is main. In case you want a link to look like a button then add class to the anchor link attribute and CSS Styling to it.